# How to format a navbar logo and title using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am attempting to make a simple navbar/menu for my website using bootstrap. I have a logo and a title, but I can not get them to align correctly. They either stack or the title is shifted all the way to the right of the navbar (as is in the provided code.) I have included the code I feel is applicable. This is my first experience with anything front end, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left">
        <img
          src="img/logo-placeholder.png"
          height="115"
          width="115"
          alt="company logo"
        />
      </a>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give img the classes `d-inline-block` and `align-top`. Check out the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo-placeholder.png" height=115 width =115 alt="company logo" class="d-inline-block align-top">
            <h1 class="d-inline-flex">Title</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still get the same issue (stacking of the elements) when I put the title in an h1 tag. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm edited the snippet. I give h1 the class `d-inline-flex`. Because h1 is block element. Check out the snippet.